# IE float div wrapping

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer-7, css-float

I'm having a problem with floating divs and IE7. For example, the following HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' lang='en' xml:lang='en'>
  <head>
    <title>IE Float Test</title>
    <style>
      .container {
        width: 200px;
        background: #ddd;
        overflow: hidden;
      }
      .item {
        float: left;
        padding: 5px;
        background: #eee;
        margin: 5px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="item">This is a item</div>
      <div class="item">This is another item</div>
      <div class="item">Last item</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Give's the following in chrome (plus other major browsers):

[image: Chrome Result]

But, the following in IE7:

[image: IE Result]

How do I get IE7 to move the item div to the next vertical position if it is too wide?

Many thanks, John.

Comment: Is this valid HTML? There's a comma in the `<html>` tag: `lang='en', xml:lang='en'>`

Comment: Thanks Blender - I fixed it. Same results though!

Comment: Why are you floating them if you want them stacked in the first place?

Comment: Hi DA, I don't really want them stacked - my example just wasn't very good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding [`white-space: nowrap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/white-space) to `.item` works: http://jsbin.com/ifexuf/2

Is that acceptable?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add min-width property to the .item

Comment: But what value do I use? I don't know how much text will be in each item and I only want the item to be as wide as the text it contains. If multiple items are small enough, I want them to be in the same vertical position.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the items stacked, there is no need to "float:left" in your ".item" CSS style. Block level elements like `<div>` appear stacked by default.